# Derivative being 0 and Projection becoming a chart on Riemann Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm self-studying the module, [Belyi Maps and Dessins d'Enfants](https://math.mit.edu/%7Esschiavo/Courses/Belyi-Sp21/index.php). At the end of lecture 1's notes [link](https://math.mit.edu/%7Esschiavo/Courses/Belyi-Sp21/Notes/Lecture%201.pdf), there is a motivating example for the subsequent study.

[image]

But, at the second line, I am finding it difficult to link the derivative $F_y (P) \neq 0$ and the projection $(x, y) \mapsto x$ onto the x-axis becoming a chart.
Is there any result connecting them or am I missing something else?
Could anyone help me to understand?

** This relation is actually used subsequently to prove the Lemma 4 of Lecture 4's notes;

[image]

Comment: This is the inverse/implicit function theorem.

Comment: @ThePuix, thank you for your comment. I know what the theorem is but Can you elaborate a bit more? Like I don't see how the theorem relates to the projection being a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) states that there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $0 = f(x,y) \Longleftrightarrow y=g(x)$ in a neighbourhood of the point $(x,y)$.

In other words, the projection $\pi_x:U\to V:(x,y)\mapsto x$ is bijective (since the points $(x,y)$, with $f(x,y)=0$, are exactly the points $(x,g(x))$ and thus completely determined by its $x$-value), meaning that $\pi_x$ maps the points of that neighbourhood one-to-one to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, wich makes it a (1-dimensional) chart.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This makes sense!!